# Spring security How redirect after succes login page with user role?

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-security

Hi i need to know how can i redirect my application after succes login page by verifying the user role just as:
if ROLE_USER redirect to accountUser.xhtml
else if ROLE_ADMIN redirect to accountAdmin.xtml

using spring security

my web.xml page is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>iTubibe</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>excite-bike</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring security filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my main-flow.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="user" class="com.ismart.itubibe.entities.UserEntity"/>

    <view-state id="welcome" view="welcome.xhtml" model="user">
        <transition on="newUser" to="signUp"/>
        <transition on="signIn" to="finish">
            <evaluate expression="userAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(user)"/>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="signUp" view="signUp.xhtml" model="user">
        <transition on="backToSignIn" to="welcome"/>
        <transition on="signUp" to="authentication">
            <evaluate expression="userServices.createUser(user)"/>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="authentication">
        <evaluate expression="userAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(user)"/>
        <transition on="yes" to="finish" />
        <transition on="no" to="welcome" />
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="finish" view="externalRedirect:account" />

</flow>
```

my spring security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/app/main" default-target-url="/app/account" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/app/logout" logout-success-url="/app/main" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServices">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userServices" />
        <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and this is my load user detail methode:

```
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

                UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByUserName(userName);

                if(user == null){
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Etulisateur introuvable '%s'", userName)); 
                }

                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getUserType()));

                User userDetails = new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassWord(), authorities);

                return userDetails;
            }
```

and the authentication methode

```
public boolean processUserAuthentication(UserEntity user) {
        try {
            Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassWord());
            Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
            return true;
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), "Sorry!!"));
            return false;
        }



    }
```

and this is my account-flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <secured attributes="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" match="any"/>

    <view-state id="admin" view="accountAdmin.xhtml">
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="user" view="accountUser.xhtml">
    </view-state>




</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hierarchical roles with [authorities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/reference/authz-arch.html) is definitely the way to go. Here is an [example](http://www.javaenthusiasm.com/spring-boot-security-with-thymeleaf/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the role of authenticated user by:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    auth.getAuthorities();
```

and based on this value you can perform the redirect, so:

1) In your form login add an authentication-success-handler as:

```
 <security:form-login login-page="/app/main" default-target-url="/app/account" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

2) Create the bean authenticationSuccessHandler that implement org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements
        AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
         Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 

        /*Set target URL to redirect*/
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(auth); 
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        Set<String> authorities = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return "/accountAdmin.xhtml";
        } else if (authorities.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            return "/accountUser.xhtml";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    public RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

Comment: thks for the info;
 but i need to know where can i add this?

Comment: In your login method

Comment: i just add the load user detail

Comment: I add details in my answer

Comment: thks for this info

Comment: this new bean CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler, im gonna call it in the main flow or on the security-config file?

Comment: you can add it in the security config file

Comment: they have a problem with account-flow.xml look att the questions, they redirect to "accountAdmin.xml" for all users

Answer (score 0):

i add all what u tell me to do but they redirecte all user to "accountAdmin.xhtml" my be with they have a probleme with my account-flow.xml" it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <secured attributes="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" match="any"/>

    <view-state id="admin" view="accountAdmin.xhtml">
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="user" view="accountUser.xhtml">
    </view-state>

</flow>
```

and my architeture is like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQqB8.png)

to devloppe my application i follow this videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94OvXuwqnGc